# Fortran function that returns scalar OR array depending on input

Tags: string, function, fortran

I'm trying to crate a function in Fortran (95) that that will have as input a string (`test`) and a character (`class`). The function will compare each character of `test` with the character `class` and return a logical that is `.true.` if they are of the same class<sup>1</sup> and `.false.` otherwise.

The function (and the program to run it) is defined below:

```fortran
!====== WRAPPER MODULE ======!
module that_has_function
implicit none
public

contains

!====== THE ACTUAL FUNCTION ======!
function isa(test   ,class  )
implicit none

logical, allocatable, dimension(:) :: isa
character*(*) :: test
character :: class

integer :: lt
character(len=:), allocatable :: both
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: intcls
integer :: i

lt = len_trim(test)
allocate(isa(lt))
allocate(intcls(lt+1))
allocate(character(len=lt+1) :: both)
isa = .false.
both = class//trim(test)
do i = 1,lt+1
  select case (both(i:i))
    case ('A':'Z'); intcls(i) = 1! uppercase alphabetic
    case ('a':'a'); intcls(i) = 2! lowercase alphabetic
    case ('0':'9'); intcls(i) = 3! numeral
    case default;   intcls(i) = 99! checks if they are equal
  end select
end do
isa = intcls(1).eq.intcls(2:)

return
end function isa

end module that_has_function
!====== CALLER PROGRAM ======!
program that_uses_module
use that_has_function
implicit none
integer :: i
i = 65

! Reducing the result of "isa" to a scalar with "all" works:
!         V-V
do while (all(isa(achar(i),'A')))
  print*, achar(i)
 i = i + 1
end do

! Without the reduction it doesn''t:
!do while (isa(achar(i),'A'))
!  print*, achar(i)
! i = i + 1
!end do

end program that_uses_module
```

I would like to use this function in `do while` loops, for example, as it is showed in the code above.

The problem is that, for example, when I use two scalars (rank 0) as input the function still returns the result as an array (rank 1), so to make it work as the condition of a `do while` loop I have to reduce the result to a scalar with `all`, for example.

My question is: can I make the function conditionally return a scalar? If not, then is it possible to make the function work with vector and scalar inputs and return, respectively, vector and scalar outputs?

---

1. What I call class here is, for example, uppercase or lowercase letters, or numbers, etc. ↩

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not make the function conditionally return a scalar or a vector.

But you guessed right, there is a solution. You will use a generic function.

You write 2 functions, one that takes scalar and return scalar `isas`, the 2nd one takes vector and return vector `isav`.

From outside of the module you will be able to call them with the same name: `isa`. You only need to write its interface at the beginning of the module:

```
module that_has_function
implicit none
public

interface isa
    module procedure isas, isav
end interface isa

contains
...
```

When `isa` is called, the compiler will know which one to use thanks to the type of the arguments.

Comment: Would it make sense to use `elemental`? Using a generic function avoids the restrictions inherent in using `elemental` (*i.e.* no side-effects, coupling between rank of input and output) so it's a more general and flexible technique, though one with more cognitive overhead.

Comment: yes it "would make sense" to have it an elemental function. Yet I think it is not possible because all arguments must be conformants. If you call elemental isa function with test as a vector, so you must call it with class as a conformant vector.

Answer (score 2):

The rank of a function result cannot be conditional on the flow of execution.  This includes selection by evaluating an expression.

If reduction of a scalar result is too much, then you'll probably be horrified to see what can be done instead.  I think, for instance, of derived types and defined operations.

However, I'd consider it bad design in general for the function reference to be unclear in its rank.  My answer, then, is: no you can't, but that's fine because you don't really want to.

Regarding the example of `minval`, a few things.<sup>1</sup>  As noted in the comment, `minval` may take a `dim` argument.  So

```
integer :: X(5,4) = ...
print *, MINVAL(X)        ! Result a scalar
print *, MINVAL(X,dim=1)  ! Result a rank-1 array
```

is in keeping with the desire of the question.

However, the rank of the function result is still "known" at the time of referencing the function.  Simply having a `dim` argument means that the result is an array of rank one less than the input array rather than a scalar.  The rank of the result doesn't depend on the *value* of the `dim` argument.

As noted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015240/3157076), you can have similar functionality with a generic interface.  Again, the resolved specific function (whichever is chosen) will have a result of known rank at the time of reference.

---

<sup>1</sup> The comment was actually about `minloc` but `minval` seems more fitting to the topic.

Comment: Thinking of it this way, it does make sense. In this case, can I implement something like the `minloc` intrinsic, that has the optional `dim` argument?

Comment: If you want the rank to depend only on whether the argument is present (not its value) then you can do this with generics - as in the other answer.  With `minloc` _et al_. (which needn't follow the rules we programmers must) you still can't set `dim=0` and return an array.

Comment: (Note that 'present' was a poor choice in a way: this is unrelated to optional arguments.)